I installed Ubuntu in the wrong language (Italian) and cannot switch to English
I installed Ubuntu in the wrong language (Italian) and cannot switch to English.
I tried switching by the settings app but I still get parts of the terminal etc. in Italian. Is there any way I can fix it without reinstalling my OS?

What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Is everything OK except the terminal? No other issues in the GUI? If so please edit your question and add the output of running locale in a terminal.

This link may be helpful, if you are running Ubuntu Desktop.


Localization
sudo apt install language-pack-en

Keyboard configuration
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration

locales



sudo locale-gen en_US 
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales 
sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8



without asking the OP, how do you know the locale to select? Do you assume too much?
